# UIImagePickerController within a popover with cancel button in iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm showing a `UIImagePickerController` of type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` inside a popover in iPad. I initialize and present the popover like this:

```
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                               initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                   inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                 animated:YES]
```

This displays a "Cancel" button on the popover's top bar in iOS 7 right to the "Photos" title. Tapping this button does nothing and I don't find the way to handle it, how can I manage the tap event to dismiss the popover, or just remove this "Cancel" button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add this:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

//DO WHATEVER WHEN YOU PRESS CANCEL BUTTON (PROBABLY DISMISSING THE POPOVER
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that method is called and then I needed to add `[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`